# Phalcone Mac and xampp

Tags: php, xampp, phalcon

Hi I have hard times with phalcon framework and xampp on my MacBook Pro, I tried how they suggest in phalcon web page with brew and all it is ok when type brew search phalcon I can see the different versions, but can not find phalcon.so to add in my xampp php.ini. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Doesn't the brew process include it automatically in the php.ini file?

Comment: I don't know maybe I installed that xampp after when I brew phalcon, but I found the solution. I'm going to add it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

I found phalcon.so in this location: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/phalcon.so

so in my /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini I added this:

```
extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/phalcon.so
```

and now seems to work fine.

Comment: Thak you!! in my case was: extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56-phalcon/2.0.13/phalcon.so